# Grepping byte offset values for data blocks of specific type in a binary file, but it's skipping blocks containing any byte larger than 127 [or 0x7F]

Tags: linux, grep, binary-files

I have a binary file containing blocks of data. The first four bytes of each block contains a fixed byte string, five bytes after that contains the block's "type" byte. I want to find out the byte offsets of each block of a specific type. So I executed the following (note that I'm using `head` here to keep my snippets short):

```
$ grep -oaPb '(\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e)' input.bin | head -n4 | cut -d: -f1
0
58
137
281
```

This would give me the byte offsets of all data blocks in the file. Looking at a hex editor...

- Block at offset 0 = type `0x0440`
- Block at offset 58 = type `0x0540`
- Block at offset 137 = type `0x0541`
- Block at offset 281 = type `0x0C80`

I want to filter for type `0x0541`, so I executed this next, but it's skipping many blocks. They're still technically correct when I checked with the editor, though:

```
$ grep -oaPb '(\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e)[\x00-\xFF]{5}(\x05\x41)' input.bin | head -n4 | cut -d: -f1
3173
4617
14078
15959
```

I know for certain that the block at offset 137 was of type `0x0541`, so what happened here? Some help would be appreciated!

EDIT: After further tinkering, I figured out that this part of the expression `[\x00-\xFF]{5}` is ignoring any match that contains a byte of value larger than `0x7F`, so it seems to be using a signed value range (-128 to 127 [0x7F]). I suppose the question now is, how do I make it so that it uses an unsigned range instead?

EDIT 2: Turns out the solution was to use `LC_ALL=c`...

```
$ LC_ALL=c grep -oaPb '(\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e)[\x00-\xFF]{5}(\x05\x41)' input.bin | head -n4 | cut -d: -f1
137
3173
4617
14078
```

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer! It's okay to answer your own questions when you figure things out on your own.